# TomCat stores logs with delay

Tags: tomcat, logging, jenkins, delay

Since monday I've been working on setting up the CI server Jenkins. Today I've noticed, that files like catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log and tomcat6-stderr.YYYY-MM-DD.log of today does not contain some of errors and stacktraces that I see in my browser. It's strange, but the messages and stacktraces of yesterday are there. Does anybody know something about this kind of delay?

Answer (score 0):

Try in "localhost.YYYY-MM-DD.log", Most of the errors you can find in this file.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I don't find there the logs I've just seen on the screen. The localhost.*.log is just empty (size = 0). That's what bother me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in catalina.log and tomcat6-stderr.log ?  Our configurations don't add a datestamp to the log until the logging system rolls them over (DailyFileAppender or something like that) at midnight.